# Delphi - Indy Client/Server sending buffer

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to send buffer from client to the server...Buffer revived but i get error message **'data error'** *while converting the buffer into steam on the server side*.

Also i tried to send that buffer as a **Stream** but i get error message on the server side **Out of memory**

Client:

```
procedure TAudio.Buffer(Sender: TObject; Data: Pointer; Size: Integer);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Buff:string;
begin
  Move(Data^, ACMC.BufferIn^, Size);

  if AConn.Client.Connected then begin
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(ACMC.BufferOut^, ACMC.Convert);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Buff := ZCompressStreamToString(Stream);
    AConn.Client.IOHandler.WriteLn(Buff);
    Stream.Free;
    Writeln('sent');
   end;
end;
```

Server Thread:

```
  try
    List := MainForm.idtcpsrvrMain.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      if List.IndexOf(Ctx) <> -1 then
      begin
        TMainContext(Ctx).Queue.Add(EncryptStr('AUDIO|2|'+BYTES));
        Stream:
         Buffer := TMainContext(Ctx).Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
         mStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
         try
          ZDecompressStringToStream(Buffer,mStream);
          mStream.Position := 0;
          SetLength(Buffer,mStream.Size);
          mStream.ReadBuffer(pointer(Buffer)^,mStream.Size);
          SendMessage(hLstbox,LB_ADDSTRING,0,lparam(Buffer));
          iList := SendMessage(hLstbox,LB_GETCOUNT,0,0);
          SendMessage(hLstbox,LB_SETTOPINDEX,iList-1,0);
          ACMO.Play(Pointer(Buffer)^,Length(Buffer));
         finally
           mStream.Free;
         end;
          if NodesList.Items[index].TerminateAudioThreads then
          begin
            ..
            ..   
            Terminate;
          end
          else goto Stream;
```

**Note:**

both **ZCompressStreamToString** & **ZDecompressStringToStream** functions are tested on the client side and its worked.

Comment: If you want to send compressed data, consider attaching a `TIdCompressionIntercept` component to the `IOHandler.Intercept` property on each side of the connection. You don't need to compress/decompress manually.  And why are you displaying the raw audio data in a ListBox? You are not processing string data.

Comment: In any case, on the server side, why are you processing data outside of the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event? The logic you have shown belongs inside that event. Chances are that `ReadLn()` is returning corrupted data, because `TIdTCPServer`'s internal thread for the `TIdContext` connection is reading data for that connection, and then you are reading data for the same connection as well, so you are going to get the server out of sync with itself, and cause data to be put into the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` in the wrong order.  All reading operations really need to be done in the server events only

Comment: @RemyLebeau I attached the `TIdCompressionIntercept` on both connection with **CompressionLevel 9** and processed the the data on `OnExecute` event but i get the following error **Max line length exceeded.** its sames the compression not working for some reason. The implementation was as follow **Server:** _TIdTCPServer.OnConnect_ `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept := IdCompressionIntercept1;` **Client:** `AConn.Client.Connect;`
`AConn.Client.IOHandler.Intercept := AConn.IdCompressionIntercept;`. Regarding the listbox i use it to print the return of DateTimeToString but to validate the

Comment: return of encryption and  compression functions i was testing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I send it as stream and worked perfectly,Thanks for your notes regarding the `OnExecute` helped a lot.